# What is the difference between a GMenu and a GtkMenu?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gtk3, gnome-3

I've been trying to add an icon to an app indicator menu with no success, and I've been using `GtkMenu`.

I found some code that referenced `GMenu` and used `g_menu_set_icon` to display an icon next to the menu label.

What is the difference between these two sets of menu's?  Should one be used in favor of the other?  GMenu appears to be more full featured, but if I'm supposed to use `GtkMenu` how would I display an icon?

I have tried this which didn't work.  It showed the label text but not the icon.

```
GtkWidget* NewMenuItemWithIcon(const char* name)
{
  GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 6);
  GtkWidget *icon = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name("status", GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU);
  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(name);
  GtkWidget *menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new();

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), icon);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), label);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(menu_item), box);
  return menu_item;
}
```

---

Update:

It would seem that GMenu doesn't inherit from GtkWidget. So it's a different kind of menu.  However, app_indicator_set_menu expects a GtkMenu not a GMenu so the correct menu to use is GtkMenu.

However, the issue of icons remains.  I was able to get it working with the deprecated api `gtk_image_menu_item`

But it's deprecated.  So ideally I shouldn't use it.  The code above comes directly from api docs. Claiming to be equivalent, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: FYI, there is no harm in using a deprecated API, AppIndicator just pre-dates this and doesn't make use of GMenu directly which is fine it will continue to work until Gtk4.